# How to retain order of original vector when using factor as a key

Tags: r

I want a way to rapidly map from one vector to another using a named vector as a key. This is easily done as follows:

```
    source_col <- state.abb[1:5]
    source_col
    AL AK AZ AR CA 

    map <- state.region[1:5]
    names(map) <- state.abb[1:5]  
    new_col <- map[source_col]
    new_col
    AL    AK    AZ    AR    CA
    South  West  West South  West
```

However, in my actual use case I have millions of rows and more complicated character strings, so this mapping is very time consuming. When I first convert my source col to a factor, the mapping occurs much more rapidly, but the returned vector is ordered according to the factor levels, rather than the original source_col:

```
source_col <- as.factor(source_col)
new_col2 <- map[source_col]
new_col2
   AK    AL    AR    AZ    CA 
 West South South  West  West
```

I would like to be able to use the speed of matching with factors, but I want the returned object to retain the ordering of the original source_col.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: `factor(source_col, levels = source_cols)` is what you want, I think

Comment: yes, that does the trick. Though my actual use case involves lots of repetition in the source column, so I used `factor(source_col, levels = unique(source_col)). Thx.